# Changing Fabric API Key and Build Secret programmatically

Tags: firebase, react-native, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have an app that is intended only for a small audience and the only way to determine if a user belongs in that audience is by logging in.

Therefore, I would like Fabric to start collecting data about the app's usage once the user has logged in to get rid of the noise in the Fabric dashboard (data collected from random users who downloaded the app).

What needs to be accomplished:

- Fabric should **start tracking** the user activity once he successfully logged in
- Is should be possible to change the Fabric API Key and Build Secret at runtime instead of build time between **debug** and **release**
- Fabric API Key and Build Secret should be set programmatically (using something like `Fabric.with()` or `Crashlytics.startWithAPIKey()`) at **runtime and not during the build**

The app is written primarily in React Native. I am also considering using Firebase or other alternatives for tracking app usage.

Currently I am setting **API Key** and **Build Secret** in the following places:

Build Phases in Xcode (Run Script Phase):

```
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Release" ]; then
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run" <RELEASE_API_KEY> <RELEASE_BUILD_SECRET>
else
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run" <DEBUG_API_KEY> <DEBUG_BUILD_SECRET>
fi
```

`Info.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Fabric</key>
    <dict>
        <key>APIKey</key>
        <string>${FABRIC_API_KEY}</string>
        <key>Kits</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>KitInfo</key>
                <dict/>
                <key>KitName</key>
                <string>Crashlytics</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
    ...
</dict>
</plist>
```